# Presentation Image CSS - javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html, image

I would like to add an image that covers the main page of my website.
This image should then disappear after a few seconds.
I tried but the image takes the space of the elements under ruining everything.
How can I do?
Thank you!!!!`

I apologize if I have not immediately provided an example
I simply tried to use CSS to make the image disappear

```
    #fadeout {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: 1s opacity;
    text-align: center;
    font-size:32px;
  }

  p {
    text-align: center;
  }
```

Then I tried to make the image disappear with javascript:

```
 window.onload = function() {
  window.setTimeout(fadeout, 3000); 

}

function fadeout() {
  document.getElementById('TEST').style.opacity = '0';
}
```

Comment: Can you provide code of what you tried so far?

Comment: Howdy, welcome to SO. You might go take a peek at the help FAQ about creating a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when asking for help. Generally folks benefit from seeing an attempt on your own not just to know they're not doing your work for you, but to help better understand your expected result. Do that and you'll have answers in no time. Cheers.

Comment: I'm sorry...i've added example

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would just do a quick css anim as a simple fake splash loader like;

```css
@keyframes reveal {
 0% {opacity: 1;}
 75% {opacity: 1;}
 99% {opacity: 0;}
 100% {opacity: 0; display: none;}
}

#splash-loader {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  background: lightgray url('https://i.imgur.com/bX2Uk7C.jpg') no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: reveal 6s ease forwards;
}


#spinner {
  height: 10rem;
  width: 10rem;
  margin: 5rem auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
}
```

```html
<div id="splash-loader">
 <div id="spinner"></div>
</div>

<h2>Hey I'm your normal content, howdy</h2>
```

Hopefully it gives you a direction for imagination. Cheers