# GIF. loading before the page

Tags: html

Okay! So when a person click on the link that leads to the other page I want that the GIF. shows first for atleast 4 seconds and then the page. I dont want the GIF. loading when the page loads. Just... the gif. shows first then the page after 4 sec. I couldn't find a code anywhere about this part. Only about a gif loading before the page loads completely. I just want the gif first and only on the page showing then the page shows itself.

I tried many codes given on this site but this ain't it chief.

Comment: please share code what you have tried so far

Comment: Could you create a page containing only the GIF and forwarding the client after the length of the gif?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO! Your question is pretty broad and missing an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to better communicate your issue. As it sits if I'm understanding correctly though you could do something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53340338/presentation-image-css-javascript)

Comment: First, you need to insert you page assets at the bottom of the page (before </body>). Next, your gif should be placed as dataURL image: `<img src="data:image/gif;base64,(...)">`, so you can be sure that be loaded quickly with your document before other assets. Then place a script with `setTimeout()` with your intended time and use this timeout to hide the gif and show other page elements.